# HTML 5 Video. Returning playback error with source element instead of attr

Tags: javascript, html, video, error-handling

I'm looking to add some error handling to a simple HTML5 video element.
Im using this chunk of code which appears everywhere [online](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#the-video-element):

**JS**

```
function playbackFailed(e) {
   // video playback failed - show a message saying why
   switch (e.target.error.code) {
     case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED:
       alert('You aborted the video playback.');
       break;
    case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK:
      alert('A network error caused the video download to fail part-way.');
      break;
   case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_DECODE:
      alert('The video playback was aborted due to a corruption problem or because the video used features your browser did not support.');
      break;
   case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED:
     alert('The video could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.');
     break;
   default:
     alert('An unknown error occurred.');
     break;
   }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<video id="a" src="tgif.vid" autoplay controls onerror="playbackFailed(event)" poster="http://img.rasset.ie/000736d2-512.jpg" width="620" height="400"></video>
```

Above works fine and I get a snappy alert box when the page loads.

However if i dont have a "src" attribute and instead use the `<source>` tag within the `<video>` element "onerror(event)" doesn't fire? Example markup:

```
<video id="b" autoplay controls onerror="playbackFailed(event)" poster="http://img.rasset.ie/000736d2-512.jpg" width="620" height="400">
    <source src="tgif.vid">
</video>
```

Note I've given both videos elements above the ids "a" and "b".

Can someone explain why in the following code:

```
<script>
var a = document.getElementById('a');
var b = document.getElementById('b');

a.addEventListener('error', function(e){alert('error event on a')});
b.addEventListener('error', function(e){alert('error event on b')});

</script>
```

I only get an alert for "a" and not "b"

I need to use the `<source>` tag as I'll have multiple media type for different devices etc.

Thanks in advance for any answers / comments

S

Comment: Have you verified it with other browsers?

Comment: Try adding the listener to the source tag for b and not the video tag

Answer (score 9):

If sources are involved, [errors in loading sources must be caught from the `<source>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Error_handling) themselves. However, to check if all of the `<source>` elements failed, [check the `<video>` element's `networkState` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Detecting_when_no_sources_have_loaded) if it's `NETWORK_NO_SOURCE`.

More details on the following here:

- [HTMLMediaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLMediaElement)
- [`<source>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/source)
- [Using HTML5 audio and video](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video)

[Here's a sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/99KwN/1/) when the first source fails to load and outputs an error into the console:

HTML

```
<video id="b" autoplay controls poster="http://img.rasset.ie/000736d2-512.jpg" width="620" height="400">
    <source src="tgif.vid" />
    <source src="http://html5doctor.com/demos/video-canvas-magic/video.mp4" />
    <source src="http://html5doctor.com/demos/video-canvas-magic/video.webm" />
    <source src="http://html5doctor.com/demos/video-canvas-magic/video.ogg" />
</video>
```

JS (using handlers to avoid inine scripts)

```
var sources = document.getElementsByTagName('source'),
    i;

for (i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        sources[i].addEventListener('error', function (e) {
            console.log('Error loading: '+e.target.src);
        });
    }(i));
}
```

Comment: Hi Joseph the network state for the above is "3" and the video plays.

If I put dummy videos into the above example thus resulting in a fail. It is still 3.

I actually need to display the error.

Comment: @sidarcy hmm... try inspecting the error (that's the `e` in the handler). As far as I have tested, an error in the `<source>` does not mean an error in `<video>` (video's `error` property is null). I haven't gone that far with error trapping in videos.

Comment: The link for `networkState` doesn't quite work right. It should be: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/networkState